# How to hide horizontal gridlines keeping the vertical Y-axis on the L.H.S

Tags: highcharts

I have a graph which looks like:

http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&biw=1148&bih=538&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=ImVcaOUrw9RZ8M:&imgrefurl=http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/stack-columns-in-order-of-size-with-vba/&docid=Wy54Uzfs1JDBAM&imgurl=http://peltiertech.com/images/2009-05/StackChart4.png&w=502&h=331&ei=4fxlUOLCFMzSigLesIGYDQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=271&vpy=229&dur=1078&hovh=182&hovw=278&tx=195&ty=91&sig=113812968337335397921&page=1&tbnh=132&tbnw=199&start=0&ndsp=10&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0,i:77

But I want a graph which looks like: http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&biw=1148&bih=538&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=NFn2T8iaojOpvM:&imgrefurl=http://peltiertech.com/Utility/ClusterStackUtility.html&docid=_9NYGInExJfrmM&imgurl=http://peltiertech.com/Utility/pix/clusterstackcolumns.png&w=282&h=207&ei=4fxlUOLCFMzSigLesIGYDQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=509&vpy=237&dur=85&hovh=166&hovw=226&tx=52&ty=80&sig=113812968337335397921&page=1&tbnh=150&tbnw=203&start=0&ndsp=10&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:0,i:80

*** ABOVE ARE JUST AN EXAMPLE OF THE GRAPH TO SHOW WHAT I WANT. NO INTENTION COPYING ANYTHING. THESE ARE RANDOM IMAGES FROM GOOGLE SEARCH.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Jugal if you visit both the links pasted above, in the first image there are horizontal gridlines but no vertical Y-axis. In the second image, there are no gridlines but one vertical Y axis on the left. I want to build something like second image.

Comment: I tried:                                                              yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0
}                                                                                 But this is just hiding the horizontal gridlines, I still cant see the vertical Y-axis on the left. Thanks fot your help in advance.

Comment: @RicardoAlvaroLohmann Ironically, Google led me here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are various options available in the [highchart yAxis object](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis), allowing you to customize it in almost any & every way.

```
  yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
   //     tickColor: 'black',
        tickLength: 5,
        tickWidth: 1,
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x:-10,
            y:5
        },
        lineWidth:1,
      //  lineColor:'black'
    }
```

I highly encourage you to have a look at the awesomely useful [highcharts api](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock)

["Hiding grid line but retaining ticks | Highchart & Highstock" @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/djtN3/)

Comment: Thanks Jugal. That worked. I didn't know that they are called as ticklength. This is the first time I am working on the highcharts. :)